# Why does an exception occur when clicking on treeview nodes in winforms application?

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I have a problem with treeview nodes.  When I click on some nodes, it brings up an unhandled exception has occured and says "object reference not set to an instance of an object".

I think that this exception occurs because I am using treeview.node.parent and treeview.node.firstnode methods in the mouseclick event.

Could you help me explain why this exception is happening?

I think the error is in this fragment:

```
private void treeNode_AfterSelected(object o, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e )
{
    // 
    if (e.Node.FirstNode != null && e.Node.Parent!=null && e.Node.Parent.Text == "Tables")
    {
        this.Controls.Remove(dg);
        this.dg= dal.showTable(e.Node.Text,e.Node.Parent.Parent.Text);
        this.dg.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(this.tr.Width + 1, this.menuStrip1.Height + 2);
        this.dg.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(n - dg.Location.X, 300);
        this.dg.BackgroundColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        this.tableName = e.Node.Text;    
        this.Controls.Add(dg);

    }

    else if (e.Node.FirstNode == null && e.Node.FirstNode.Text == "Tables")
    {
       dal.changeDatabase(e.Node.Text);

    }
}
```

p.s sorry for bad english

Comment: It would be very helpful if we could see your code that is throwing the exception.  Thanks.

Comment: A Stackframe, a Stackframe, my kingdom for a Stackframe!

Comment: @Simon: You have a kingdom? O.O. Gimme a sec and I'll make a stackframe for you xD

Comment: i understand my fault, thanks for help everybody

Comment: `if (e.Node.FirstNode == null && e.Node.FirstNode.Text == "Tables")` - that's just plain wrong!

Comment: yes, i edited that, it was the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you will click on parent nodes (1-st level) and then call

`node.Parent.SomeMethod` you will get NullReference exception because its Parent is `null`

Put some validation in order to check whether Parent is not null

```
if(node.Parent != null)
{
  // do stuff
}
```

Same situation is for node.FirstNode - it will return `null` if there is no children for this node, so also put validation for this

```
if(node.FirstNode != null)
{
  // do stuff
}
```

**EDIT:**
in your snippet `e.Node.Parent.Parent`  some of parents can be null and `e.Node.FirstNode` can be null so you end with exception

```
if (e.Node.Parent != null && e.Node.Parent.Text == "Tables")
{
    this.Controls.Remove(dg);
    if(e.Node.Parent.Parent != null)
    { 
       this.dg= dal.showTable(e.Node.Text,e.Node.Parent.Parent.Text);
       this.dg.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(this.tr.Width + 1, this.menuStrip1.Height + 2);
       this.dg.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(n - dg.Location.X, 300);
       this.dg.BackgroundColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
       this.tableName = e.Node.Text;    
       this.Controls.Add(dg);
    }
}
else if (e.Node.FirstNode != null && e.Node.FirstNode.Text == "Tables")
{
   dal.changeDatabase(e.Node.Text);

}
```

Comment: @Stecya sorry i didn't see that you edit and i edited by my new version of code, which also isn't work, can you edit again ?

Comment: See code in my answer. You definitely are not checking `if(e.Node.Parent.Parent != null)`

Comment: i don't need to check node.parent.parent because in my program the nodes with name tables always have 2 parents

Answer (score 1):

I'd also like to add that there is a VERY annoying bug in the default TreeView. I don't remember the exact details, but I've met it often. Perhaps it's fixed in VS2010, but it definitely was there in VS2008.

The basic idea was that after clicking (or doubleclicking?) the treeview contents scrolled, either because the node expanded/collapsed, or because it was partially visible and then scrolled into view (don't remember now). As a result, your mouse pointer was no longer over that node. I think that in the collapsing case it could even end up being over no node at all (empty area). In turn this caused the click/doubleclick event to have the wrong node in the argument, or perhaps even null if the mouse was over the empty area. This way you can easily get your `NullReferenceException` even though you did nothing wrong.

Comment: i work with vs2010, if the cause of bug what you say, how can i fix that ?

Comment: @Vahan - well, do check if it is, but if it is, there was a workaround... I think it involved checking the node on the click (or the mousedown?) event, and then storing that. On doubleclick then you checked the previously stored node, not the one in eventargs.